# FreeBSD xfce not working

Tags: xorg, freebsd, xfce

M I have installed xorg and xfce and added entry to xinitrc but when I type startx my pc displays the message "not support!", what to do?

I did this as root.

Comment: Try as NON-root! And if it doesn't work please post your ~/.xinitrc.

Comment: as root it shows :"exec /usr/local/bin/startxfce4" , as non-root it says it's not found

Comment: Please post your ~/.xinitrc! "non-root it says it's not found" - please copy the EXACT message!

Comment: I am sorry ,but now,I reinstalled the OS again and ran these commands in this order : "pkg install nano";"pkg install xorg";"pkg install slim";"pkg install mate-desktop mate".Then I opened /etc/rc.conf and added to the file "dbus_enable="YES"";"hald_enable="YES"";"slim_enable="YES"".Then i opened .xinitrc and added "exec mate-session" and then I added "exec mate-session" to /home/james/.xinitrc   .When I boot the OS my  monitor shows "Not support!" .I know it's not xfce but I have followed a tutorial just to get a desktop.

Comment: Typically, a user should be following the Handbook for such things, especially when, in this case, XFCE installation is contained there: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x11-wm.html

Answer (score 2):

Install the `xinit` using  `pkg install xinit`

And still if you getting same error try using bellow wich might resolve your problem

`pkg install xorg` this is only for GUI